# phpMyAdmin in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, phpmyadmin

I am trying to become a devoted Chrome user however this is just one problem. I also spend a lot of time inside of phpMyAdmin and for some reason I cannot seem to resize the frame.

Is there an extension out there that fixes this problem?

Comment: Which version of chrome may this be?

Comment: Currently I am on version 12.0.742.122, but I first noticed this in the first release.

Comment: Update to a more recent version and try agian

Answer (score 0):

This is corrected in the latest version of Chrome and PhpMyAdmin (as of Jan 2013). Please upgrade and try again.